# How to validate input array with a same name in laravel controller

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have a problem when a i try to insert record into table like this .

```
$data = array();

foreach($input['user_id'] as $key => $user_id) {
    $data[$key]['user_id'] = $user_id;
}
foreach($input['start_on'] as $key => $start_on) {
    $data[$key]['start_on'] = $start_on;
}
$this->validate($request, [
    'time_start' => 'required|date',
    'time_end' => 'required|date|after:time_start',
]);
$rules = [
    'start_on' => 'required|date|after:time_start|before:time_end|different:start_on'
];

// Iterate and validate each question
foreach ($data as $value)
{
    $validator = Validator::make( $value, $rules );

    // if ($validator->fails()) return $validator->messages()->all();
}
```

I want to check start_on not equals another start_on.So what can i do?

Comment: You want `start_on` to be unique ?

Comment: yep, it's what i mean

Comment: So try to add `unique` role to start on `'start_on' => 'unique|required|date....`

Comment: i thing unique just work with database.I saw it in document.I tried, but not working

Comment: My solutions is using array_unique($start_on, SORT_REGULAR), and it's working.Tks!

Comment: You're welcome, good job, you can post an answer for the futur readers.